# How to identify processes spawned by a .Net app connecting to POSTGRESQL

Tags: c#, .net, windows, postgresql

I have a C# .net application that connects to a postgresql database.

Experimentation shows that every connection made from the application creates a new `postgres.exe` process visible in task-manager and traceable in the database.

The C# app has a PID, the postgres connections it spawns also have PIDs, how can the app establish the PID it just created?

I'd like to establish which C# connection results in which database process. I naively assumed that the parent PID of any database connection would match the PID of the application that created the connection. This doesn't appear to be the case.

The best bodge I've managed is to list the postgres.exe processes immediately prior to creating the connection

```
Process[] processBefore = Process.GetProcessesByName("postgres");
```

Then make the connection

```
NpgsqlConnection myDatabaseConnection= new NpgsqlConnection(myConnectionString);
```

Then list all the postgres processes present afterwards

```
Process[] processAfter = Process.GetProcessesByName("postgres");
```

Then compare the two lists and assume that the new process is the one established by the connection.

In practice this seems to work most of the time, but other processes can create  (and remove) `postgres.exe` instances, so there's scope for cock-up.

Is there a better/easier/more reliable way of doing this?

UPDATE - Why do I need to do this? - **Fault-finding**. I have several different instances of the C# app all making multiple connections to the database. I can monitor all the database sessions, (and their operating system PIDs) from the postgres dashboard. Some of those sessions are running dodgy SQL that's causing problems (conflicts/locks/etc).

Since I don't know the PID of the connection, I can't link the dodgy SQL back to it's source in the app. The basic problem seems to be that although I know the PID of the app, and the app creates the connections, the connection does NOT have a parentPID that matches the app.

Comment: _Why_ are you doing this?

Comment: I don't know much about Postgres, other than it's an RDBMS and that you presumably communicate with it over the network. You seem to be assuming that your application is creating the postgres.exe instance itself (and thus your app would have the parent PID), rather than assuming that the Postgres server is the thing spawning the postgres.exe processes, perhaps in response to incoming connections. Why do you need to know which spawns which? What problem is that going to help you solve? Seems like this may be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: In SQL Server the DBMS itself keeps track of which database session is connected to which client process (Client computer name & PID) which you can get with SQL queries.  Perhaps postgres sql has a similar facility?

Comment: @RBarryYoung "SQL Server the DBMS itself keeps track of which database session is connected to which client process (Client computer name & PID)" - yes, but that's only as a _convenience_ and as an aid to troubleshooting. There is nothing stopping a custom TDS client (for SQL Server) sending completely bogus client-side name and PID info. Rule #1 in distributed-systems is to _never trust the client_.

Comment: @Dai The question above is not phrased as a security question, but appears to be asking from the perspective of the client process making the connections so this should not be a problem.  And again, postgres SQL may be completely different.